# Priority Search - SQL

Tags: sql

Consider a user enters a keyword to search for books. First the application searches by book title matches, if more than 50 books matches the search then it returns results; if not, it searches by book author matches. If together no more than 50 books matches, if then searches by book description matches.

Can SQL handle this situation? Or I have to write a stored procedure with ifs and elseifs?

[added] I use MySQL5.6. But I feel like the answer lies in in ANSI-SQL so I didn't specify it. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I've provided an answer which should work in the most DBMS maybe with some changes. But please provide your DBMS, as it would help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can realize it using `union all` with subqueries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(50) bookname
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(50) bookname, 1 as rank
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE bookTitle = N'BLA'
    UNION
    SELECT TOP(50) bookname, 2 as rank
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE bookAuthor = N'BLA'
    UNION
    SELECT TOP(50) bookname, 3 as rank
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE bookDescription = N'BLA'
) as data
ORDER BY rank
```

This works on SQL Server. On MySQL you need to use `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`. 
You should specify which server you use in your tags.

EDIT (by other user):

This is an accepted answer, but it has a problem because it might return duplicates.  A book that matches all three conditions can be returned three times.  The `union` doesn't eliminate them, because the `rank` is different on each row.

One solution is to remove the rank and use a `case` statement in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when bookTitle = N'BLA' then 1
               when bookAuthor = N'BLA' then 2
          end)
```

EDIT by author:
I changed the code above using the defined column names and a distinct, which will preserve duplicate entries.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` there is *no* guarantee that the first 50 rows returned from that `UNION` are (if they exist) 50 rows that met the `bookTitle` condition.

Comment: Yes your right, I've forgotten that in the heat of the fight. :-D Just added it on the example.

Answer (score 3):

One approach to this is to do all the comparisons using a single query and then prioritize the results.  The ANSI standard syntax would be like this:

```
select b.*
from books b
where Title . . . or
      Author . . . or
      Description . . . 
order by (case when Title . . . then 1
               when Author . . . then 2
               when Description . . then 3
          end)
fetch first 50 rows only
```

Of course, the final clause is not supported in all databases, so it might be `limit` or `top` or something even worse.

If you have a large table, and performance is an issue, there are other ways to phrase the query, depending on what the matching conditions look like.